# How to get the current exception without having passing the variable?

Tags: c#, exception

I am looking for a way to retrieve the current exception without having to pass it as a variable.

Suppose the following code

```
public void MakeItFail()
{
    try
    {
        throw new FailException();
    }
    catch // Yes I'm aware that this shouldn't be done, but I don't want to go through all the code base and change it
    {
        ShowMessage("An error occured");
    }
}

public void ShowMessage(string message)
{
    // How can I retrieve the exception here
}
```

In the watch window, I can use $exception to get the current exception. Is there is a code equivalent?

Comment: What you are thinking about doing is bad.  Very bad.  Stop it.  Don't do it.  No.  Not for you.  Don't.  Grab a copy of framework design guidelines and read the exception handling section.

Comment: @Will - I don't suppose you would like to work on rewriting their app?

Comment: I don't know how big the codebase is, but I strongly suspect the time it would take to go back and fix all of the catch clauses would be less than the time required to implement and test the workaround hack, discounting even the time required to maintain it in the long run.

Comment: @Dan - I suspect that it is their only option. I just felt that @Will was being a little too hard on their practices without knowing the situation.

Comment: No its not the only option, but it is an option.

Comment: @Will I'm well aware of that. I've been tasked to know the exception at a precise point in the software. Not to rewrite how the whole Feedback system work with those badly written exception handling. But I will forward your answer to my boss: I will tell him to read the design guideline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You need to use a parameter.

Comment: I've read about some possible but hard way using the ICorDebugThread.GetCurrentException() but I didn't try it.

Comment: That's part of the unmanaged debugger API.  You can only use it on a process that's paused in a debugger.  Since a process cannot debug itself, you'd need to write a second process to debug the first one and call that API.

Comment: And I am not going down that rabbit hole :P

Comment: This is the choosen answer because we assigned someone to changes all catch block to properly pass the exception to our feedback system.

Comment: There is actually: `var exceptionBeingThrown = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers() != IntPtr.Zero;`

Answer (score 7):

Try subscribing to this event when you first load your app.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s, e) =>
{
    ShowMessage(e.Exception.Message);
};
```

Comment: aww that.net 4 only. This is an existing program and we are not converting it to 4.0 yet